# Error: ER_CANT_CREATE_THREAD: Can't create a new thread (errno 11);

Tags: server, mysql

When the server A ran a node.js application connecting to two seperate mysqldb servers B and C. The server A reported the errors as follow:

```
Error: ER_CANT_CREATE_THREAD: Can't create a new thread (errno 11); if you are not out of available memory, you can consult the manual for a possible OS-dependent bug
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (/home/abc/workspace/node_modules/my$
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/home/abc/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/prot$
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/abc/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/prot$
    at Parser._parsePacket (/home/abc/workspace/node_modules/mysql/lib/prot
```

RAM configuration for mysql db server B and C is 192GB, Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS Server, mysql 8, and its mysqld.cnf file configured as:

```
max_connections = 100000
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 20G
tmp_table_size = 1G
max_heap_table_size = 1G
read_rnd_buffer_size = 1G
thread_cache_size = 100000
open_files_limit = 1000000
table_definition_cache = 40096
table_open_cache = 1000000
```

Someone has any idea for this problem.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common solutions for this situation is to update the soft `nproc` limit for MySQL. This is how you can do it:

1. Open a terminal
2. Edit the limits configuration file:
   `sudo vi /etc/security/limits.conf`
3. Look for a line that starts:
   `mysql soft nproc`
4. Update the value from the default of `2048` to `4096`
   (If you don't see a line like this at all, you can add it to the bottom of the file: `mysql  soft  nproc  4096`)
5. Save the file & restart MySQL

This will boost the soft `nproc` and allow the server to create more threads. Based on the hardware configuration you outlined, the system will have more than enough power to handle this.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I am wondering that why the value just range from 2048 to 4096. Why it cannot be 10000, 100000, or more. Actually, I tried the value from 2048 to 4096 and it did not solve the problem. Are there another solution?

Comment: Anyone can help me solve this problem in Ubuntu 18 server? I have tried to configure parameters as suggestions on google, but the problem has not yet been resolved.